# How to have Command-W close a window on Mac OS in Java or Clojure

Tags: java, macos, clojure, keyboard-shortcuts

I'd like to have <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> close a window/`JFrame` in a program I am writing in Clojure. How might this be accomplished? Pure Java solutions are also welcome.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
 Action closeWindow = new AbstractAction("Close Window") {
   @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     // window closing code here
   }
 };
 closeWindow.putValue(Action.ACCELERATOR_KEY, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(
     KeyEvent.VK_W, Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMask()));
```

Put that `Action` in a menu on your menubar. The accelerator will be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> on Windows.

Probably better would be to use the [Keybinding API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) to have the main panel in each `JFrame` (assuming there are multiple) bind the same `KeyStroke` as above in its (`WHEN_FOCUSED`) input map to an action in its action map that closes the frame.

```
public class ClosableWindow extends JFrame {
  public void setUp() {
    JPanel mainPanel = createMainPanel();

    int mask = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMask();
    KeyStroke closeKey = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, mask);

    mainPanel.getInputMap().put(closeKey, "closeWindow");        

    mainPanel.getActionMap().put("closeWindow", 
        new AbstractAction("Close Window") {
          @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            setVisible(false);
            dispose();
          }
        });

    getContentPane().add(mainPanel);      
  }
}
```